# how to deal with if statement in for loop in R

Tags: r

```
a <- c("CA", "ON", "TX", "FL", "CO")
b <- c("CA", "ON", "TX", "FL", "CO", "AB", "IL", "NY", "WA")
```

I want to compare a and b, and change "AB" "IL" "NY" and "WA" to "other". something likes this,

```
 b <- c("CA", "ON", "TX", "FL", "CO", "other", "other", "other", "other")
```

This is only a sample, the original dataset is huge, I need to do it in an easy way.

Comment: Do note that this is a different problem than would be faced by someone tryig to modify this object: `dataframe( b =c("CA", "ON", "TX", "FL", "CO", "AB", "IL", "NY", "WA") )` , because that would be a factor column.

Answer (score 2):

If I get it right it is about building a difference between *a* and *b* and substitute extra items with `"other"`:

```
b[!is.element(b, a)] <- "other"
```